# Information on month old flights

Tags: air-travel

Where can I get flight info for a flight a month ago for an insurance claim? Flight stat sites will only show a weeks worth of data.

Answer (score 3):

If this is for a travel insurance claim, you should probably contact the airline directly.

FlightAware.com provides 4 months of historical data to registered (free) users for US Domestic and some international flights.

Answer (score 2):

Flightstats [historical flight search](http://www.flightstats.com/go/HistoricalFlightStatus/flightStatusByFlight.do) can give you runway arrival and gate arrival times for years into the past. You need to create a free account to do so.